# Intuition Behind Unbiased Estimators

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, bayesian, parameter-estimation

Let $X^\theta=X^\theta_1,\dots,X^\theta_p$ be a random variable depending on a parameter $\theta\in\bf{R}$.

One way of defining 'correctness' of an estimator $e:\bf{R}^p\to\bf{R}$ for $\theta$ is to demand $E(e(X^\theta))=\theta$ for all $\theta$ (unbiased estimator).

However, the more intuitive approach for me would be chosing some prior distribution of $\theta$ such that $(\theta,X^\theta)$ has continuous probability density and demanding for $e(x_1,\dots,x_p)$ to pick the unique maximum in the density line along $X^\theta=x_1,\dots,x_p$.

Is this intuition of any worth?  If yes, are there important scenarios where it coincides with the definition of unbiased estimator?

Comment: Your approach asks the estimator to confirm your previous choice of prior distribution. That's called confirmation bias. It is the opposite of unbiased.

Comment: @HansEngler OK, but isn't this a non-trivial philosophical problem, that there exists no neutral prior on $\bf{R}$ (like one could argue the uniform distribution serves for compact carriers)?  So that I can't be unbiased when entering a scenario in which a real-valued random parameter comes into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbiasedness can be a very bad thing in some instances. This is not my new discovery but one example of it is: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206006.pdf

What you're describing is sometimes used, and the posterior expected value is also often sometimes used. It is well known that methods based on posterior distributions can avoid pathologies afflicting unbiased estimation.

And there are things like the [James–Stein estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator), which is not even a decision-theoretically admissible estimator and yet is superior in mean-square-error sense to all unbiased estimators.